# SQL Join based on a pattern

Tags: sql, join, pattern-matching

I have two tables tmpModels and tmp_product. Need to find matching models based on the model in tmpModel.
 For example, If `tmpmodel.updatedmodel ='amb3771'` and `tmp_product.updatedmodel` could be `'amb3771bian' or '123abc3771xv'` then we have a match. 
Meaning that the tmp_product.updatedmodel should contain a matching pattern from tmpmodel anywhere in the updatedmodel column.

I have actually created a stored procedure but here is a snippet checking the behaviour for one particular value.

```
declare @model1 nvarchar(255)
set @model1 = 'amb3771'

select g.updatedmodel as GFK,p.updatedmodel Product from dbo.tmpModels g
join dbo.tmp_product p
on g.updatedmodel= substring(p.updatedmodel,PATINDEX('%@model1%',p.updatedmodel),LEN(@model1))

select @model1
```

I am expecting only two rows to be shown in the result. I don't understand why a different value is being assigned to `@model1` even though I am forcing it to 'amb3771' and strangely there is no result matching 'amb3771'!! Please help me understand why this logic doesn't work and give the desired result. Below is the result -

```
GFK   Product
w679    w679
t754cw  t754cw
wa5714  wa5714silber
fl2823  fl2823
dc7230  dc7230
wda100  wda100
wa74sd  wa74sd
ev9547  ev9547
wa5714  wa5714weiss
wa7439  wa7439
wda210  wda210wpm
wda210  wda210wpm
w194    w194
wda110  wda110wcs
wa5714  wa5714silber
wda100  wda100
```

Comment: `PATINDEX('%@model1%'` - why is `@model1` wrapped in 's?

Comment: Ugh. For the query you show, you are doing a complete table scan of tmpModels. Then, for every row in that table, you are doing a complete table scan of tmp_product. That could be an awful lot of table scans for an expected two-row result. Even if you filter the tmpModels rows, there is no way to make the join criteria sargable. Your best long term strategy is to work out a simple connector between 'amb3771' and 'xxxamb3771xxx'. There must be something that connects the second to the first besides an embedded string. If something doesn't exist already, create it.

Comment: @DLeh,Thanks! Oh the quotes. I couldn't catch it and kept worrying only about he logic the whole time.

Comment: @TommCatt We are trying to bring together data from two different source which are similar and somehow later map them to one structure. This investigation is to know the data and similarity in modelnames between these two sources. I will definitely check if there is anything can be used as a connector. Tmp_product(1500 rows) is relatively smaller than tmpmodels(400,000 rows). Of course the tables are growing and this will change in future. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

First of all as DLeh mentioned `@model` should not be in quotes.

> I don't understand why a different value is being assigned to @model1
>   even though I am forcing it

No different value is assigned to `@model`

If you execute query below you can see PATINDEX is returning 0 and then substring is getting full value of p.UpdateModel from 0th index to its length

```
select g.updatedmodel as GFK,p.updatedmodel Product, PATINDEX(@model1,p.updatedmodel) 
from dbo.tmpModels g
join dbo.tmp_product p
on g.updatedmodel= substring(p.updatedmodel,PATINDEX(@model1,p.updatedmodel),LEN(@model1))
```

One solution I can suggest is to use `WHERE` condition instead of `JOIN`

```
set @model1 = '%wa5714%'

    select DISTINCT g.updatedmodel as GFK,p.updatedmodel Product
    from dbo.tmpModels g
    , dbo.tmp_product p
    WHERE PATINDEX(@model1,p.updatedmodel) > 0
    AND  PATINDEX(@model1,g.updatedmodel) > 0
```

I am assuming your model should display values of tmpModel and tmp_Product.

If you have different requirement the provide more details/example

Comment: BIG Thanks. This helped me understand somewhat the workings of the sql statement I wrote. I mostly used your solution to  get the desired result. I have however saved other snippets that gave me wrong result and I will be back to discuss those sql statements again here. For now, you saved my day.